# qPow() in QtMath increase CPU usage

Tags: cpu, qtmath

Any explanation on different CPU usages from these two scenarios:

1. when using qPow(x,2), CPU usage 14%;
2. instead x*x, drops to 3%

I just write a simple Qt UI dealing with some img processing.

Very appreciated to any feedbacks!!

For qPow(x,2), it is Okay to use x*x; but what if I need qCos for instance.

Comment: try `ldexp()` for speed.

Comment: ldexp() gives a usage in between, about 7%.

Comment: `pow(x, 2)` is a special case where there's a huge amount to gain from manually optimizing to not call a function at all, especially not one that accepts arbitrary floating-point powers so works by `exp(log(x) * power)` or similar.  For `qCos` or standard C `cos`, is you input always 0 or pi/2?  If so, just compare and pick between `1.0` or `0.0`.  Otherwise, it's not a special case that can be computed much more quickly.  Depending how much precision you need, you might use a faster approximation than the math library, e.g. with lower degree polynomials.

Comment: Also, for image processing you're presumably doing the same thing to a lot of pixels, so you want to take advantage of SIMD.  With the right compiler options, some compilers may be able to vectorize `cos`, computing 4 or 8 return values in parallel for 4 or 8 different inputs.  IDK how `qCos` is defined, whether the compiler can see through it to the actual `cos` and potentially vectorize.